# Flutter graphql using cache with hive, when calling query with police 'cacheAndNetwork' it always uses the network without the cache

Tags: flutter, caching, graphql, flutter-hive

Flutter graphql using cache with hive, when calling query with police 'cacheAndNetwork' it always uses the network without the cache

Here is caple of my code

```
    Future<QueryResult> query(String query,
      {Map<String, dynamic> variables}) async {
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions(
      document: gql(query),
      variables: variables,
      fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.cacheAndNetwork,
      errorPolicy: ErrorPolicy.none,
      cacheRereadPolicy: CacheRereadPolicy.mergeOptimistic,
    );

    final result = await _client.query(options);

    return result;
  }
```

It returns always from the network, actually, it should work how it's described in the documentation of graphql "**'cacheAndNetwork' returns result from cache first (if it exists), then return network result once it's available.**"

Here is my GraphQL client

```
  GraphQLClient _client;
  Client httpClient;

  void initClient(session) {
    if (_client != null) return;

    final token = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

    final HttpLink _httpLink = HttpLink(
      'https://*************/graphql',
      defaultHeaders: {
        'x-api-key': '************',
        'Content-Type': '*************'
      },
      httpClient: this.httpClient,
    );

    final AuthLink _authLink = AuthLink(getToken: () => token);

    final Link _link = _authLink.concat(_httpLink);

    _client = GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(
        store: HiveStore(),
      ),
      link: _link,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please read @Hive tag info and do not use it for questions like this. Hive tag is used for completely differnt product. There is flutter-hive tag, use it, or create your own tag please